# How to avoid using self in Python class methods?

Tags: python

I am trying to implement a LinkedList in Python and below is the code I have written for the same.

```
from linkedlists.Node import Node


class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def insert_at_beginning(self, data):
        temp = Node(data)
        if self.head is None:
            self.head = temp
        else:
            temp.next = self.head
            self.head = temp

    def insert_at_end(self, data):
        temp = Node(data)
        if self.head is None:
            self.head = temp
        else:
            curr = self.head
            while curr.next is not None:
                curr = curr.next
            curr.next = temp

    def insert_at_position(self, pos, data):
        temp = Node(data)
        if self.head is None:
            self.head = temp
        else:
            curr = self.head
            i = 1
            while i < pos:
                curr = curr.next
                i += 1
            temp.next = curr.next
            curr.next = temp

    def traverse_list(self):
        if self.head is None:
            print('List is empty')
        else:
            curr = self.head
            while curr.next is not None:
                print(curr.data)
                curr = curr.next


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ll = LinkedList
    ll.head = Node(1)
    ll.insert_at_beginning(10)
    ll.traverse_list()
```

When I run the code, I see the run time exception:

```
TypeError: insert_at_beginning() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Thats because I have a method parameter `self` in the method definition.
I can't remove the `self` parameter because I am initializing the head to `self` in the constructor.

Is there anyway I can call the methods without `self` or if I can construct all of my logic without using `self` ?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `ll = LinkedList()` is what you need. Right now you're not instantiating an object, just making `ll` be an alias for the class name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a new object of a class you have to use parenthese (round brackets) after the class name
Change:

```
ll = LinkedList
```

to:

```
ll = LinkedList()
```

Comment: True, this will instanciate the class to get an object that will have the given attributes and metthods.